# Emit in vue does not upgrade property in parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The emit works, I can see that in the vue developer tool. But the property in the parent element does not upgrade.

Child Component:

```
<template>
  <div>
      <ul>
          <li v-for="(option, index) in options" :key="index" @click="selectOption(index)">
              {{ option }}
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "Dropdown",
    props: {
        options: {
            type: Array,
        },
    },
    data() {
        return {
            value: "",
        }
    },
    methods: {
        selectOption(id) {
            this.value = this.options[id];
            this.$emit("clickedOption", this.value);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Parent Component:

```
<button v-on:clickedOption="selectRole($event)">Select Role</button>

methods: {
        selectRole(value) {
            this.role = value.payload;
        },
```

It seems that the function `selectRole` is not getting executed.

Answer (score 0):

I had to give the parent element the emit function like this:

```
<Dropdown :options="roleOptions" v-show="dropdownToggle" @clickedOption="selectRole($event)"></Dropdown>
```

Comment: i think it should be clickedoption....cuz vue doesn't allow all uppercase in emit names i guess

Comment: I have always used camelCase for events and never had a problem. I believe it is suggested to use kebab-case for events, like `@clicked-option`. Always works.